# convert day of week, Month, day year to d/m/y

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following in excel:

```
Saturday, June 11 2011
```

I would like to convert this into the standard dd/mm/yy format.

What would be the easiest way to do this (in either excel or VBA)?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use Excel's [CDate function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdate.php), you first have to get rid of the leading text marking the day. Assuming this is always with a trailing comma and space, you could do the following:

```
Sub changedtformat()
Dim rawdate As String, cleandate As Date, resultdate As Date

rawdate = "Saturday, June 11 2011"
cleandate = Mid(rawdate, InStr(1, rawdate, ",") + 2, Len(rawdate))
resultdate = CDate(cleandate)
MsgBox resultdate 

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you need a comma separating the day and year for CDate to work?

Answer (score 1):

With your text in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999)," ",", ",2))
```

and format anyway you like.  We just make a string that `DATEVALUE()` can handle.